# Set dynamic custom style for ListView items in monodroid?

Tags: android, android-listview, rss

I have a ListView for RSS, which I  populate dynamically. I  want to set style for items.
how can I do so?

Comment: My Friend ... this link will help you ...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560675/monodroid-splash-screen

Comment: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=454

Comment: Thanks ,but my question was about ListView style

Comment: For that you have to create custom layout and use LayoutInflater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bullet"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mCustomList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#666666"
        android:dividerHeight="0.05dp"
        android:scrollingCache="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

CstListAdapter.java

```
public class CstListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<CstItem> postList = new ArrayList<CstItem>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Context ctx;


    public CstListAdapter(Activity act, ArrayList<CstItem> d, Context ctx) {
            activity = act;
        postList = d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return postList.size() < count ? postList.size() : count;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text= (TextViewPlus) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.img= (TextViewPlus) row.findViewById(R.id.img);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        CstItem item = postList.get(position);
        holder.text.setText(item.getTitle());

        return row;
    }
```

CstItem.java

```
public class CstItem {

    private String title;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String url;
    private String description;
    private String pubDate;


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }
...

}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    private ListView mListView;
    private CstListAdapter cstListAdaptor;
    private ArrayList<CstItem> PostList = new ArrayList<CstItem>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mCustomList);

        cstListAdaptor = new CstListAdapter(this, PostList, this);

        mListView.setAdapter(cstListAdaptor);
        PostList.clear();

        refreshRss();

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                CstItem cit = PostList.get(position);
                String cnt = cit.getDescription();
                //...

            }
        });
    }
...

}
```